# how to make aws elastic mapreduce hive commands run in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I reviewed here,

[How to make hive run mapreduce jobs concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868186/how-to-make-hive-run-mapreduce-jobs-concurrently)

My question is how to set this "hive.exec.parallel.thread.number" option in an Amazon EMR cluster on startup?

Also, is setting this option equivalent to doing something like the following?

```
cat hive_script.hql | parallel --gnu hive -e '{}'
```

My hive script can run in any order, as it is simply launching a bunch of jobs for each new (time based) partition of an existing table to create time based partitions of a derivative  table.

If they are not equivalent in my case, will one of these strategies yield better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question is how to set this "hive.exec.parallel.thread.number" option in an Amazon EMR cluster on startup?

add configuration into `hive-site.xml` (In my case, file path is `./.versions/hive-0.11.0/conf/hive-site.xml`)

```
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.parallel</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Whether to execute jobs in parallel</description>
</property>
```

If they are not equivalent in my case, will one of these strategies yield better performance?

It's different. This property controls different stages paralle in one hive job, so performance depends on specific hive query.

Comment: is there a way to tell a newly launching emr cluster to have this property, perhaps using the bootstrap actions? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#PredefinedbootstrapActions_ConfigureHadoop

Comment: I found you can specify --hive-site on startup  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-cli-commands.html