# How to allow apache hive to handle multiple clients query

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, client-server, hive

I have created an external table via hive from hbase. When someone loged in to shell and deploy some queries , no one else can run any query. when someone try to run a quesry it gives following error.

FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

when first shell exits then queries can be run easily. So it means that my hive a cannot handle multiple clients. How to enables it to handle multiple clients

Comment: which version of hive you are using ?

Comment: hive version is hive-0.11.0

Answer (score 1):

If you have not configured your Hive Metastore, its not possible for more than one user to access the Hive Server.

> **Embedded Metastore** An embedded metastore is mainly used for unit tests. Only one process can connect to the metastore at a time, so it
>   is not really a practical solution but works well for unit tests

Check this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-LocalMetastore) for more information.

Comment: How to configure hive metastore so that it can be accessed for kmore than one user

Comment: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html

Comment: link you provided is not what I suppose to have information. I have a directory metastore_db in hive home on my system that is storing metastore information. Now if two users access hive (via ssh ) and run queries, only one is successful while other give error like Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeExcepti. So you can think that I have my local metastore but it does not allows multiple users. How to solve it

Comment: the one you are using is the default one.. derby. you cannot let multiple users use your server in that case.

Comment: you have to install a database. may be mysql. run the init scripts. configure corresponding things in the hive config.