# rank() 20M records in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

when i run this sql, it takes about half a hour and it's unacceptable.
the source table have 20M records.

each rank() create a mapreduce job running for 7 minutes with all the data in one reduce. how to optimize this sql? can these rank mapreduce run in parallel?

```
create table tmp.xxxx  as                                       
SELECT t.end_user_id,   
t.pm_net_amt,    
t.parnt_ordr_num,
rank() over(order by t.pm_net_amt) pm_net_amt_rank,
rank() over(order by t.parnt_ordr_num) parnt_ordr_num_rank, 
rank() over(order by t.cat_lvl3_num)  cat_lvl3_num_rank,
rank() over(order by t.discount_rate) discount_rate_rank 
from  bi_tmp.bbbbbb t;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [How to make hive run mapreduce jobs concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868186/how-to-make-hive-run-mapreduce-jobs-concurrently):

> In hive-default.xml, there is a property named "hive.exec.parallel"
>   which could enable execute job in parallel. The default value is
>   "false". You can change it to "true" to acquire this ability. You can
>   use another property "hive.exec.parallel.thread.number" to control how
>   many jobs at most can be executed in parallel.

That may cause each of the ranks to be run in parallel, but I have not tested.

Comment: the parameter hive.exec.parallel is already set  TRUE  and hive.exec.parallel.thread.number = 8 .